# DataTables display issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using a plugin from http://datatables.net/ for displaying data in a table. I am using the server_processing.php script and it is returning data.  The issue is that all of the records are being returned at the top of the page, then at the bottom the plugin works correctly.

The page can be viewed at https://www.egoodbyes.com/site/pagin.php

The php file is

```
<?php
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

/* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
$aColumns = array('fname', 'mi', 'lname','occup', 'age', 'dod', 'town','state');

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "vic_id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "victims";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "xxx";
$gaSql['password']   = "xxx_RT";
$gaSql['db']         = "xx_xxx";
$gaSql['server']     = "xxxx";

/* REMOVE THIS LINE (it just includes my SQL connection user/pass) */
//include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/datatables/mysql.php" );


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/* 
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}


/* 
 * MySQL connection
 */
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}


/* 
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
                ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/* 
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`)
    FROM   $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

This is the HTML

```
       <?php 
include ('server_processing.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<!--<link href="css/shThemeDataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">-->
<!--<link href="css/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">-->
<!--<link href="css/doc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">-->
<link href="css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php"
    } );
} );

</script>
</head>

<body>

<table id="table_id"  class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>MI</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Branch of Service</th>
             <th>Age</th>
              <th>Date of Death</th>
               <th>Town</th>
               <th>State</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td></td>


        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

I have asked the question on their forum, however it is not very active, and for those not familiar, this is a pretty interesting item.

Hopefully someone can point me to where I am going wrong.

Thank you

Gary

Comment: Was all that code necessary? Please remove all this bloat-code and post only the relevant parts.

Comment: not sure of php, but this line " echo json_encode( $output ); " is this outputing the json data on to the screen?

Comment: Sujesh Arukil - Yes, but it is required (the page does not function without it) and all examples show this line as it is.  Interesting development, when I commented out this line, the results now show "Row 1 Data 1"  "Row 1 Data 2" in the columns on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the first line in the html, you dont need to include the server processing php file, the ajax call is gathering the json object for datatables to use

Comment: Jay, Thank you very much, I would not have thought of that.  Gary

Comment: My opinion is this is why stackoverflow exists, another pair of eyes, cheers